# How to loop through JSON generated in input in RESPONSIVE filemanager callback function?

Tags: php, jquery, html

In responsive file manager 9.14.0 I have used "stand-alone" method. Obviously it works pretty well. I simply upload an image and the image will be
visible in preview, and the URL will be also visible in input. The Problem is with multiple selection files, when I select more images in the file manager, it will be generated as JSON syntax in the input, and the images wont be visible in the preview. My Question is how to iterate through the JSON syntax and generate every image as single URL image in SRC address. I have tried lots of stuffs, but I am not able to still figure it out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="cs">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/4.2.2/
jquery.form.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" >
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrap">
<a href="filemanager/dialog.php?type=2&field_id=none_img" data-fancybox- 
type="iframe" class="fancy"> Insert Image </a>
<button class="" onclick="clear_img()">Remove image </button>
<div>
 <img src="img/noimage.jpg" alt="" id="prev_img"/>
</div>
<input type="text"  id="none_img" multiple>
 </div>

<script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancy").fancybox();

 });

function responsive_filemanager_callback(field_id) { 
var image = $('#' + field_id).val();


  $('#prev_img').attr('src', image);

  }

 function clear_img() {
 var imagen = 'img/noimage.jpg';
 $('#prev_img').attr('src', imagen);
 $('#none_img').val('');
 }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Debra can you post your json format data,

Comment: Sure  @Krishna Jonnalagadda originally i wanted to post it with picture for cleaner understanding, but i needed some upvotes. Here is a picture [link](http://test2.debraprivate.xyz/problem.jpg) The format with some values looks something like this: `["http://localhost/tinymce2/uploads/source/anna___frozen_by_childishx-d7g1e7i.jpg","http://localhost/tinymce2/uploads/source/anna_by_godohelp-d7aq41d.jpg"]`  format without values looks so: ["...", "...", "...", "etc"]

Comment: @Debra you can always post the code it self, I think it's better that way, in case anyone wants to copy and paste it to try to debug your code.

Comment: @Giovanni Di Toro  Yup I have edited right know... I clicked on the "Add Comment" by mistake.